# Javascript delay after click on element to wait for next page to load

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, settimeout, delay, synchronous

I'm creating a test procedure for my app and I want to have a synchronous delay of an action inside my code in order to wait for the next page to load, and then search for the selectors I need. 
I have used setTimeout but the return is not working there.

```
var myelement = "click button here";

if (myelement.indexOf("click")>=0) {
    for (var i=1; i<=4 ; i++) {
        title = document.querySelector("#element > .row:nth-of-type("+i+") > .title").textContent;
        if ( title == "title x" ) {
            document.querySelector("#element > .row:nth-of-type("+i+") > .button > a").click();
            //wait for 5sec to load next page
            var content = document.querySelector("#message").textContent.trim();
            if (content == "my content" ) { 
                return true; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I don't insert a delay, line 9 (var content) returns an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null`

Any help here?
Thanks

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way if you're trying to pause things synchronously. That said, timeouts are not synchronous, they're asynchronous. And you can't return from an asynchronous callback - it's a contradiction in terms. Look into [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Answer (score 0):

Webpages have no state without a server and database, cookies, or localStorage so if you try to do a setTimout and reload the page you will have lost the state and the function will not fire.

You need to use something like **localStorage** to save the state between page loads. Check the value of your state and take the appropriate action on page load.

```
var myelement = "click button here";

// this will be run on page load
// if the localStorage.content is set you have passed from the previous page
if (localStorage.content) {
  // check the value
  if (content == "my content") {
    console.log(localStorage.content, true)
    // reset the localStorage value
    localStorage.removeItem('content')
  }
}

if (myelement.indexOf("click") >= 0) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)(function(i) {
    title = document.querySelector("#element > .row:nth-of-type(" + i + ") > .title").textContent;
    if (title == "title x") {
      document.querySelector("#element > .row:nth-of-type(" + i + ") > .button > a").click();
      // set the localStorage value for the next page load
      localStorage.content = document.querySelector("#message").textContent.trim();
      window.location.href = '/somewhere-else'
    }
  })(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **setTimeout**, it does not work well in loops. So, use **sleep** which is implemented in the following

```
function sleep(mills){
    var t=new Date().getTime(); // Store current Time;
    while((new Date().getTime()-t)<mills);
}
```

So in a loop, you may use the `sleep` function I just created for you.